# 癒やす/癒える vs 治す/治る?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Any differences between these two for the meaning of healing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

治す (transitive) / 治る (intransitive):

- Matter-of-fact words that correspond to English *treat* or *recover*.

癒やす (transitive) / 癒える (intransitive):

- More literary. 傷が癒えた is fine in novels, but in everyday conversations, 癒える is almost never used for real physical diseases or injuries.
- Tends to focus on the passive self-restoration process typically prompted by relaxing, music, massage, *onsen*, pets, etc.
- Often assosiated with mental stress. This article about [癒やし(系)](https://japanesestudynow.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/iyashi/) seems good.
- Closer to English *heal*.